# Agora Audio Broadcasting events callback

Tags: audio-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

We are evaluating Agora Audio Broadcast API. This is a radio broadcast application and we would like to have our hosts broadcast via a admin web page served from our backend server. Is there anyway that our backend server can receive event callback such as the following:
. Channel created
. Audience joined channel
. Audience left channel

Answer (score 1):

When the host joins a channel using the .join() function, you can trigger a custom event using javascript's

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

to create and trigger a "channel-created" event.
 We already have an event for 'Audience joined' :

```
client.on('peer-online', function(evt) {
  console.log('peer-online', evt.uid);
});
```

We also have an event for the event when an audience member leaves a channel:

```
client.on("peer-leave", function(evt) {
    var uid = evt.uid;
    var reason = evt.reason;
    console.log("remote user left ", uid, "reason: ", reason);
    //……
});
```

Do get back to us if you have anymore queries.

Comment: thanks! is this documented anywhere in Agora API doc or example code?